# Spring aop:config

Tags: java, xml, spring, aop

I am new to using Spring framework... First there was this error

```
The prefix aop for element aop config is not bound
```

And then I added the following to Spring.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

Now there is Still an error

```
Error occured processing XML 'org/springframework/aop/aspectj/AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice'
```

Here is my complete xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect ref="audience">
            <aop:before pointcut="execution(* com.uttara.spring.Performer.perform(..))"
                method="takeSeats" />
            <aop:before pointcut="execution(* com.uttara.spring.Performer.perform(..))"
                method="switchOffPhones" />
            <aop:after-returning
                pointcut="execution(* com.uttara.spring.Performer.perform(..))"
                method="clap" />
            <aop:after-throwing
                pointcut="execution(* com.uttara.spring.Performer.perform(..))"
                method="boo" />
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>

    <bean id="duke" class="com.uttara.spring.Juggler">
        <constructor-arg value="15"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="poem" class="com.uttara.spring.EnglishPoem"></bean>
    <bean id="hans" class="com.uttara.spring.PoeticJuggler">
        <constructor-arg value="15"></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg ref="poem"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="audience" class="com.uttara.spring.Audience"></bean>
</beans>
```

Please help!
I have absolutely no clue.
I have a few library files. I don't know exactly what they do. Are there libraries missing? What is causing these errors? How do i fix it?

Comment: If you're new to Spring, don't start with legacy XML configuration. Use Spring Boot, and use start.spring.io to autogenerate an entire ready-to-go package to work from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using spring requires a lot of library files. `Aspectjrt`, `Aspectj-weaver`, `aop-alliance` are a few, which we don't get as spring dependancy jar files. We have do download, and add to classpath to run spring based applications successfully.

Answer (score 0):

`(...)` is incorrect way of specifying arguments(zero or more) for a Point-cut. Try replacing with `(..)` in the Point-cut expressions.